# Minimise button minimises every div instead of a single one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used a snippet of javascript code I found somewhere on my blog for a minimise button but it's not working as intended. The blog uses blocks for different kind of posts, the {block:Photo} for example.

```
    {block:Photo}
    <div class="PhotoPost">
    <div class="PhotoWrapper">                            
    <div class="Button">-</div>    
    <div class="box">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".Button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
            $(this).html("+");
            }
    else{
            $(this).html("-");
            }
            $(".box").slideToggle();
            });
    </script>

    <img class="PhotoPostImage" src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
        <!-- Some more code -->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

When I click the minimise button it minimises and maximises every single photo post as many times as there are photo posts instead of minimising the photo post where the button is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should tag this as jquery, if that's what the $ is from, and not as html5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$(".box").slideToggle();
```

to

```
$(this).siblings(".box").slideToggle();
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: nice - I missed that little part

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I click the button now, it only minimises the post it's supposed to but it still does it as many times as there are photo posts. Do you have any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Never mind, I found out what's wrong myself. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Sorry for late feedback, It was late at my country so I have to go to sleep. You should use this script block only one, and put it inside `$(document).ready()` function

Answer (score 0):

change

```
      $(".box").slideToggle();
```

to

```
      $(this).next('.box').slideToggle();

.next('.box')
.closest('box')
.siblings('.box')
```

all should work

notice that the icon html was only changing for the clicked div because you used `$(this)` , but then you called `slideToggle()` on everything with `box` class

Comment: The button doesn't seem to be doing anything when I click it. I've tried to modify it but I can't get it to work. Could you look at it again to see if there's something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @user2350481 - all of the 3 answers here will solve your problem - if it's still not working then open the F12 developer tool - go to Console , and look for errors - you probably mis typed something

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses `$('.box')` which matches every element of class `box` anywhere in the page. Instead, select only the one in the same PhotoWrapper as the button that was clicked:

```
$(this).closest('.PhotoWrapper').find('.box').slideToggle();
```

By the way, I suggest using a proper minus sign (−, `&#x2212;` in HTML, `\u2212` in JavaScript) as this will visually match the plus sign it replaces: the `-` hyphen often displays smaller and lower.

```
$(this).html('\u2212');
```

Comment: Thanks for the proper minus sign! But I still have a problem with minimising. If there are 5 photo posts the first photo minimises and maximises 5 times, the 4th post 4 times etc. Do you know what causes this?

Comment: Ah, I suspect you're repeating the script block multiple times in the page: each script adds another click handler to all the buttons that currently exist, so after five scripts have run, the first button has five handlers attached to it, and they all run when you click it! Can you output the script just once, after all the photos have been output?